# how to get text value from disabled input in selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium, text

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="dez " value="" maxlength="300" disabled="">
```

Python:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nome']").get_attribute("value"))
```

It works in enabble input's, but the "nome" input  is disable (greyed - not editable). So I cant get the text value

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below, I'm just removing the disabled attribute after verifying the visibility of the element and print the text

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH("//[@id='nome']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", element)

print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nome']").get_attribute("value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see from HTML you shared this element is not disabled since `disabled=""`.
For disabled elements it should be `disabled="true"`.
I guess you are getting empty output for `.get_attribute("value"))` here since the element simply have no `value` value.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered my question so deleted your answer. Thanks anyway, it works:
just remove disabled Attribute

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nome']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", element)
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nome']").get_attribute("value"))
```

solved

Comment: what are you getting by `.get_attribute("value"))` after applying `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", element)`?

Comment: You did not really answered. Do you now receiving non-empty output? And before it was empty string?

Comment: Yes, now I got the text value! thanks Now I just need the input go back to what it was before: disabled

Comment: Hm, interesting! But why element with attribute `disabled=""` is disabled? it should be `disabled="true"` or `disabled` like this: `<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="dez " value="" maxlength="300" disabled">` but now as you presented it. It looks strange for me.